# node.js websocket handshake draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76 doesn't work!

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, handshake

im paging my php websocket server to node.js but i don't understand, why my handshake fails! Here is my code:

```
var msg = data;
//console.log(msg);

tmp = msg.match(/\r\n\r\n(.*?)$/);
if(tmp) code = tmp[1];

tmp = msg.match(/GET (.*?) HTTP\/1.1/);
if(tmp) res = tmp[1];

tmp = msg.match(/Sec-WebSocket-Key1: (.*?)\r\n/);
if(tmp) key1 = tmp[1];

tmp = msg.match(/Sec-WebSocket-Key2: (.*?)\r\n/);
if(tmp) key2 = tmp[1];

tmp = msg.match(/Host: (.*?)\r\n/);
if(tmp) host = tmp[1];

tmp = msg.match(/Origin: (.*?)\r\n/);
if(tmp) origin = tmp[1];

tmp = msg.match(/Upgrade: (.*?)\r\n/);
if(tmp) upgrade = tmp[1];

tmp = msg.match(/Connection: (.*?)\r\n/);
if(tmp) connection = tmp[1];

tmp = key1.match(/[0-9]/g);
num1 = parseInt(tmp.join(''));

tmp = key2.match(/[0-9]/g);
num2 = parseInt(tmp.join(''));

tmp = key1.match(/\s/g);
spa1 = tmp.length;

tmp = key2.match(/\s/g);
spa2 = tmp.length;

part1 = num1/spa1;
part2 = num2/spa2;

var md5 = crypto.createHash('md5');

test1 = String.fromCharCode(part1 >> 24 & 0xFF, part1 >> 16 & 0xFF, part1 >> 8 & 0xFF, part1 & 0xFF);
md5.update(test1);  

test2 = String.fromCharCode(part2 >> 24 & 0xFF, part2 >> 16 & 0xFF, part2 >> 8 & 0xFF, part2 & 0xFF);
md5.update(test2);

md5.update(code);

var fin = md5.digest('binary');

var out = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n"+'Upgrade: '+upgrade+"\r\n"+'Connection: '+connection+"\r\n"+'Sec-WebSocket-Origin: '+origin+"\r\n"+'Sec-WebSocket-Location: ws://'+host+res+"\r\n\r\n"+fin;

console.log(out);
socket.write(out, 'utf8');
```

If someone has an idea, I would be amused :) Tryed this code with example given in v76 spec of handshake method and its ok there.

Comment: Why don't you use socket.io ?

Comment: Chrome and FF with enabled WS connect and disconnect, after HS from server is sent out.

Comment: Dont want use socket.io as i want to prog it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer [phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket) for more information.

And in the latest WebSocket protocol version [draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-09, the handshake mechanism has been updated, there will be only one "Sec-WebSocket-Key", you can learn more about the revised handshake mechanism from my article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/Web-Socket-in-Essence.aspx